# Unzipping the file in my iphone app

Tags: xcode

i am trying to unzip a file in my iphone app, i searched it on google and found this http://github.com/tastefulworks/twziparchive but it says to add libz library into your project but i am not able to find this library.
Can anybody have any idea about this or any other helpful link to perform unzipping.

Thanks,

Comment: I am the author of this library. It has since be renamed to [SSZipArchive](http://github.com/samsoffes/ssziparchive). Glad you figured it out. I should add screenshots to the readme to make this more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your project choose 'Frameworks' group (optionally), right-click and choose add 'Existing frameworks' - libz.dlyb can found in the list that will appear (you can choose dylibs in combobox) to make search a bit easier

Comment: I'm not sure about the version you need, in one of my projects I use version libz1.2.3, but I think if there's no specific requirements in your 3rd party lib then you can choose any lib version you want